# PopToRootAsync to a selected Shell Flyout Item

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, navigation

I have this code below to create an action bar with an integrated side bar using `<Shell>` so the user can navigate easily by swiping right. Being new to C#, I understand that the first ShellContent is gonna be the page to be loaded and previewed by the `<Shell>` when the app opens which is `ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoanHistory}"`

I also understand when you click on the FlyoutItems you aren't gonna add stack to the navigation but the `<Shell>` is changing the contents each time you click on it. This code below is in a file called MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoanApp2.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="LoanApp2.MainPage" BackgroundColor="#62bef0" Title="Dylan">

    <FlyoutItem Title="MyTabApp" Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">

        <ShellContent Title="Loan History" IsTabStop="False" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoanHistory}"/>
        <ShellContent Title="Apply for Loan" IsTabStop="False" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoanApplication}"/>
        <ShellContent Title="Logout" IsTabStop="False"  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoanHistory}"/>
    </FlyoutItem>

</Shell>
```

So, via the side bar (shell) - I click on Apply for Loan which takes me to `LoanApplication.xaml`. By this time, no stack is added to the navigation. In the `LoanApplication.xaml`, I'm using `PushAsync` binded to a button to take me to a page called `AmountLoanable.xaml`. This gets added to the stack and the back button on the action bar is now available.

After I am done with the stuff on `AmountLoanable.xaml`, I use `PopToRootAsync` to remove the navigation stack except for the root page (which is the `<Shell>`, `MainPage.xaml`). However, it takes me back to the "Apply for Loan" which was selected prior, what I want to happen is for it to load a fresh new `<Shell>`, `MainPage.xaml` page. In that way, the first page (Loan History) will be the one selected instead of the last page accessed via `<Shell>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to reset your `Application.Current.MainPage` to your default Shell ex: `Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();`

Comment: happy to help =)